# How to output 'i' in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, steam

I'm currently trying to see if 'steam ids' are taken; as i'm trying to get a nice one.. so i thought i'd spend 5 mins to make this little script, but no matter what i try it will never output the "list"

```
const request = require("request");
var fs = require('fs');
var list = fs.readFileSync("list.txt", "utf-8").split("\n");

for(i of list){
    request({
method: "GET",
        url: "https://steamcommunity.com/id/" + i,
}, (error, response, body) => {
    if(body.match("The specified profile could not be found.")) {
        console.log(i + "not taken");
    } else {
        console.log(i + "taken");
   }
})
}
```

The script works; and knows which ID isn't taken, and which is.. but the problem is I can't see the ID's that aren't taken - if anyone can help me then that'd be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard issue of your variable being changed in scope, and the scope not being what you expect it.

```
const request = require("request");
var fs = require('fs');
var list = fs.readFileSync("list.txt", "utf-8").split("\n");
var i;

for (i of list) {
  (function(id) {
    request({
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://steamcommunity.com/id/" + id,
    }, (error, response, body) => {
      if (body.match("The specified profile could not be found.")) {
        console.log(id + "not taken");
      } else {
        console.log(id + "taken");
      }
    })
  })(i);
}
```

As there is no scope difference between the outside (the `for` loop) and the handler of your request, the variable `i` will have changed by the time the request is over. I've added a closure to your code to make sure that a copy of this variable is present in the lexical scope, so your handler knows what ID it queried.

There are cleaner ways of doing this. In particular, you could've used an iterator to simplify this.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sébastien - I'm sure there's tons of cleaner ways to do this, but I just wanted it done - quickly and over. Your method worked perfectly and did exactly what I wanted it to do, thank you - Upvoted and will Submit as the working answer!

Comment: @Reaperz the last point was merely to nudge you on if you wanted to check further. Glad to have been of some help, though :-)